# get all data from one list item jquery mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to click on one row and get the id for posting to the db and the name to dsiplay for the user.

With this code I have to click on the corresponding `<li>` (data-id or data-name) to get that value. How to get both from a `<li>`? Hidden-fields, maybe?

```
  $(".ITA").on("click", "li", function () {
    var div = $("#AddedItems");
    var itemtoadd = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    alert(itemtoadd + name);
    var itemtoadd = ("<li class = " + itemtoadd + ">"+ name +"</li>");
    alert(itemtoadd);
    $(itemtoadd).appendTo(div);
   // div.html(itemtoadd);


});
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<ul>
    <li data-id = "@item.ID">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </li>
     <li data-name="@item.item_name">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".ITA").on("click", "li", function () {
    var div = $("#AddedItems");
    //Get the nearest parent
    var parent = $(this).closest("ul");
    //From the parent, access both li
    var itemtoadd = parent.find("[data-id]").attr("data-id");
    var name = parent.find("[data-name]").attr("data-name");
    alert(itemtoadd + name);
    var itemtoadd = ("<li class = " + itemtoadd + ">"+ name +"</li>");
    alert(itemtoadd);
    $(itemtoadd).appendTo(div);
   // div.html(itemtoadd);


});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5MqD4/)

Comment: @healix: sorry, closest instead of nearest and some typos. Check my updated answer

Comment: @healix: I also added a demo

Comment: Wow.Excellent. Would you mind explaining a little how it works? I'm still getting used to jQuery but this is real useful and not really sure how it works

Comment: you could take a look at [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/). What this code does is: from the clicked li, I get the closest ul parent using `closest`. From the ul, I easily access all its children using `find` @healix